# After hiding dialog, another dialog are hiding too

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm working with jsf pages, using primefaces, and i've got a problem:
I've a dialog, witch have a button, after clicking on that, i've another dialog (pop up).
So, my problem is that when i am closing second dialog, first dialog is closing too.

So, this is the first dialog:

```
<h:form id="propertyForm">
    <p:dialog id="propertyValuesDlg" 
              resizable="false" 
              modal="true" 
              closable="false">
        <p:panelGrid columns="1" style="width: 100%;">
            <p:dataTable var='propertyValue' 
                         value="..." 
                         id="propertyValuesTable" 
                         widgetVar="propertyValuesTableWidget" 
                         rowKey="..."
                         selection="...">
                <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox"/>
                <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox"/>
                <p:ajax event="toggleSelect"/>

                <p:column style="text-align:center; width:20px;" 
                          selectionMode="multiple"/>
                <p:column headerText="Property Name">
                    <h:outputText value="..." title="..."/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Property Value">
                    <p:inputText value="..."/>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="Add" 
                                 icon="button-add-class" 
                                 oncomplete="addPropertyDialog.show();" 
                                 update=":addPropertyDlg" 
                                 immediate="true"/>
            </f:facet>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

After clicking on "Add" button, i get second dialog:

```
<p:dialog id="addPropertyDlg" 
          widgetVar="addPropertyDialog" 
          resizable="false" 
          appendToBody="true">
    <p:panel id="addPropertyPanel" style="width: 100%">
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                <p:outputLabel for="addPropertyDropdown" 
                               value="Select property: " 
                               style="width: 80px"/>
                <p:selectOneMenu id="addPropertyDropdown" 
                                 value="..." 
                                 effect="fade" 
                                 converter="..." 
                                 style="width: 150px;">
                    <f:selectItems value="..."
                                   var=".." 
                                   itemLabel="..." 
                                   itemValue="..."/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:commandButton value="OK" 
                                 icon="button-accept-class" 
                                 actionListener="..."
                                 oncomplete="addPropertyDialog.hide();" 
                                 update=":propertyForm:propertyValuesDlg"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:panel>
</p:dialog>
```

So, any ideas, what should i do to keep propertyValuesDLg opened?

Comment: Place the Form Element two elements higher. Like <h:form><p:dialog>. This may help.

Comment: That's because you're updating the first dialog in the OK button ! Basically if you update a dialog while it's opened naturally it's going to close because the whole content has been replaced in the DOM. Try to update `propertyValuesTable` instead.

Comment: @HatemAlimam Thanks a lot, it's working for me! You may post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hatem Alimam wrote:

That's because you're updating the first dialog in the OK button ! Basically if you update a dialog while it's opened naturally it's going to close because the whole content has been replaced in the DOM. Try to update propertyValuesTable instead.